# Is there a way to copy only particular elements of xml file to a new xml file?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, xml, parsing

I have an xml file original.xml and the content of the file has the link to other files. abc.ext4,mno.ext4 and pqr.ext4 are 3 different files.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
    <DATA DEST="mb">/dev/abc.ext4</DATA>
    <DATA DEST="mb">/dev/mno.ext4</DATA>
    <DATA DEST="mb">/dev/pqr.ext4</DATA>
</COLLECTION>
```

Now I need to calculate the size of these individual files(each line) if the file_size > 10MB I need to copy and paste these xml lines to a new file(original.xml)

Example: If the size of abc.ext4 and pqr.ext4 > 10 MB then the new xml (original.xml) should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<COLLECTION>
    <DATA DEST="mb">/dev/abc.ext4</DATA>
    <DATA DEST="mb">/dev/pqr.ext4</DATA>
</COLLECTION>
```

How to handle this in Python?

Comment: Have you looked at `ElementTree` in the standard library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is the problem?

Comment: Also, a note on terminology: you don't really talk about lines in XML, but rather elements.

Comment: @mzjn So far I have calculated the sizes using os.path.getsize () but I'm not sure how to map it to a particular element and move it to a different file

Comment: Take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Using SaxonC (which has a Python API), run the following XSLT transformation:

```
<COLLECTION xsl:version="3.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:file="http://expath.org/ns/file">
  <xsl:copy-of select="DATA[file:size(.) gt 1e7]"/>
</COLLECTION>
```

[Disclaimer, SaxonC is my company's product. You need the Professional Edition or above, which costs GBP 50]